# JSON.parse ReferenceError: parse is not defined

Tags: json, node.js, express

I receive "ReferenceError: parse is not defined" when running the following line in Node V6.11.0 inside an express router.

```
router.post('/api/addComp', function(req,res) {
   var tempData = JSON.parse('{"compName":"Bodhi\'s Test", "compStreet":"12312 Glendale Av", "compCity": "Los Angeles", "compZip":"90039"}');
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This code tests in the browser console and should be a part of Node by default from my understanding.

Comment: Actually strange… Try a `console.log(JSON)`.

Comment: yeah, quite strange, any other info you can possibly give?

Comment: what do you mean that it tests in the browser console?

Comment: that error doesn't sound right, are you using a library called parse? can you share the error?

Comment: So sorry, don't code after wisdom teeth removal.  4 lines down from JSON.parse I had incorrectly typed `parse.Int(variable)` as opposed to `parseInt(variable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse('{"compName":"Bodhi\'s Test", "compStreet":"12312 Glendale Av", "compCity": "Los Angeles", "compZip":"90039"}');` was working as expected.  Later lines of code had incorrect syntax for `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

The error "ReferenceError: parse is not defined" will never occur because the method parse of JSON do not exist. Since you are calling it as an function executing the error thrown would be  "JSON.parse is not a function", case JSON was not instantiated it would throw "cannot call parse of undefined". Some where else in your code you have a call to parse alone, separated by a typo error, like a coma or maybe  a semicolon. Usually this error will only be thrown by an undeclared variable in strict mode.